# Show vim buffers matching a pattern

Tags: regex, vim

In vim, I can show all the open buffers by running the `:buffers` command, however, sometimes the list can get long, is there a way to limit the output to only filenames matching pattern?

For example:

[image]

How would I only show the *.c files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> after the wildcard:

```
:b *.c<Ctrl-D>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have `:buffer *.c^D` (where `^D` mean you type <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd>).

Or, if this is about writing a plugin:

```
echo join(map(filter(copy(range(1, bufnr('$'))), 'buflisted(v:val) && bufname(v:val) =~ ".*\\.c"'), '" ".fnamemodify(bufname(v:val), ":p")'), "\n")
```